# Best Practive to Synchronize Server time with Users Time

Tags: javascript, time, browser, server, utc

I have not tested but I presume the UTC time/date on a Users environment(Web Browsers) will be derived from what their host computer has been set to. If I offset my time by maybe by 10 minutes, my computer's UTC time will also be late by 10 minutes which will not represent the global/internet time.

Trying to find the difference between my time that is 10 minutes late and a global time from another server that is synced with the internet time will yield an unpredictable result.

What is the best practice to handle this scenario given an instance that requires letting the user know how long ago an activity occurred on the server in seconds?

Comment: The computer always should use a NTP client, which will handle the time syncrhonization. Indeed, without a valid time/date in your computer, you won't be able to make any HTTPS request, so internet will be useless.
I would assume that the user time is valid; but if you want to know how many minutes ago somehting happened, just ask to the server with a request: give me the date/time of the event AND the difference between the event time and the current (server) time

Comment: I faced this with a time tracking feature, when the server clock was wrong by a couple of minutes and using NTP to have it right was apparently out of the question. My thought was to provide server's UTC time in a `data` HTML attribute so JavaScript could calculate and apply a offset in seconds (network time was acceptable) to all local dates. But I never managed to implement it.